# Dúvidas sobre Picker em Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, android, sql, visual-studio, xamarin

Estou criando um aplicativo móvel em que o usuário possa cadastrar x ingredientes e posteriormente possa cadastrar produtos escolhendo quais dos ingredientes cadastrados tal produto usa. Nesta perspectiva:

**Dúvida 1**: Estou tentando popular um Picker tendo como referência os dados da tabela ingredientes preenchida pelo usuário, mas estou travado na hora de digitar a parte de conexão e adaptação da table... Como posso fazer isso?

**Dúvida 2**: O Picker permite ao usuário selecionar apenas uma opção, ao que parece... Há forma de fazer selecionar múltiplas opções? Ou talvez alguma ferramenta substituta (nesse caso, precisaria de saber como popular essa tal ferramenta com os dados da tabela).

Classe Picker: https://pastebin.com/2iFZWbhs

```
public class PickerMVVMViewModel
{
    public List<listIng> listarIng { get; set; }

    public PickerMVVMViewModel()
    {
        listarIng = GetIngs().OrderBy(t => t.Value).ToList();
    }

    public List<listIng> GetIngs()
    {
        var ing = new List<listIng>()
        {   // essa parte supostamente receberia os dados da tabela, mas fiz esses itens para checar o funcionamento.
            new listIng(){Key = 1, Value= "Pão"},
            new listIng(){Key = 2, Value= "Carne"},
            new listIng(){Key = 3, Value= "Ovo"},
            new listIng(){Key = 4, Value= "Presunto"},
            new listIng(){Key = 5, Value= "Queijo"},
            new listIng(){Key = 6, Value= "Bacon"}
        };
        return ing;
    }
}


public class listIng
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

XAML que implementa o Picker: https://pastebin.com/pPj64c7t

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="OrganizeSe.cadProduto">

    <StackLayout Margin="10,10,10,0">
        <Entry  Placeholder="Insira o nome do produto"                
                FontSize="20"/>

        <Label Text="Selecione os ingredientes:"
               FontSize="20"
               TranslationX="5"
               TranslationY="15"/>

        <Picker Title="--Selecione--"
                ItemsSource="{Binding listarIng}"
                ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Value}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Content que se encontra a table: https://pastebin.com/v66JJSJt

```
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class NewIngPage : ContentPage
    {
        public NewIngPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Ingredientes ing = new Ingredientes()
            {
                Nome = nameEntry.Text,
                Preco = precoEntry.Text,
                Qnt = qntEntry.Text
            };

            using (SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
            {
                conn.CreateTable<Ingredientes>();
                var numberOfRows = conn.Insert(ing);

                if (numberOfRows>0)                
                    DisplayAlert("Salvo!", "O ingrediente foi salvo com sucesso.", "Ok");
                else
                    DisplayAlert("Falha!", "O ingrediente NÃO foi salvo.", "Ok");
            }                        
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pare de postar links e imagens para o seu código, inclua as partes relevantes em sua pergunta

Comment: Colocando todo o código não torna mais fácil o entendimento? Afinal, estão enxergando como um todo a estrutura do que estou fazendo. Também por esse motivo, upar no pastebin se torna conveniente.

Comment: Tente ser mais específico em sua pergunta, pesquisando, fazendo suas próprias tentativas até chegar a um erro concreto. Se é necessário que vejamos TODA a sua estrutura para entender o problema é porque a sua pergunta ainda não está clara e muito ampla.

Comment: É isso, não é um erro ou um problema, é só algo que quero fazer, mas não sei como, e dessa forma eu quis dar uma explanação do que quero e onde quero para que alguém possa me explicar com mais exatidão, mas entendo o que você quis dizer baseado nos meus posts anteriores. Farei da forma explicada.

Comment: Mas esse não é o intuito desse site, procure exemplos na internet e faça o exercício de entender exatamente qual é a sua dúvida. Veja que o cerne da questão muito pouco tem a ver com Xamarin, android ou o próprio componente Picker, se trata de como fazer uma consulta no SQLite. Pesquise sobre isso e resolva essa questão primeiro.